# Is "Mutation" Cheaper than "Calculating Derivatives"?

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis

When it comes to optimizing objective functions belonging to Statistical and Machine Learning Models, there seems to be a general rule:

- High dimensional objective functions with many parameters are "computationally expensive" to optimize

As such, there tends to be two general types of algorithms that are used to optimize objective functions:

- **Gradient Descent:** Gradient Descent tries to find the minimum point (i.e. "optimize") of these objective functions by repeatedly calculating the derivatives of these objective functions, and moving in the direction of these derivatives.
- **Evolutionary Algorithms:** Evolutionary Algorithms (e.g. Genetic Algorithm) also try to find the minimum point of these objective functions, but instead of repeatedly evaluating the derivatives of the function, they work by "randomly moving in many directions at the same time, and probabilistically moving more in those directions that are producing lesser values of the function". This is called "mutation and crossover" - I have greatly simplified the process.

**My Question:** As the number of dimensions in the objective function increases, it becomes more and more computationally expensive to repeatedly evaluate the derivatives of the objective function- since Evolutionary Algorithms do not need to repeatedly evaluate these derivatives, they are said to be "computationally cheaper" compared to Gradient Based Methods. Although there have been no major results established on the convergence of Evolutionary Algorithms (whereas many theoretical results have been established on the convergence of Gradient Based Methods) : **For the exact same objective function - do we know precisely how much cheaper "Crossover and Mutation" costs us compared to "Evaluating  Derivatives"?**

There still seems to be some costs associated with "Crossover and Mutation" (e.g. randomly storing, sorting and permuting well-performing "chromosomes" i.e. past solutions) - but do we know how much cheaper this costs us compared to evaluating derivatives (e.g. can we bound this using some Big-O Landau Notation or using Linear vs. Polynomial Time)?

Thanks!

**Extra:** Comparison of Gradient Descent and Genetic Algorithm for Optimizing the Rastrign Function using the R Programming language

**1) Genetic Algorithm**

```
library(GA)

start.time <- Sys.time()



  #define function to be optimized
Rastrigin <- function(x1, x2)
{
  20 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x1) + cos(2*pi*x2))
}

x1 <- x2 <- seq(-5.12, 5.12, by = 0.1)

#run optimization through the genetic algorithm (with constraints)
GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness =  function(x) -Rastrigin(x[1], x[2]),
         lower = c(-5.12, -5.12), upper = c(5.12, 5.12), 
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 1000, run = 100)

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
```

**Results:**

```
 time.taken

Time difference of 1.266233 secs

GA@solution
                x1          x2
[1,] -4.947186e-06 3.72529e-07
```

**2) Gradient Descent**

```
library(pracma)

start.time <- Sys.time()

Rastrigin <- function(x)
    {
        return(20 + x[1]^2 + x[2]^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x[1]) + cos(2*pi*x[2])))
    }

 steep_descent(c(1, 1), Rastrigin)

end.time <- Sys.time()
    time.taken <- end.time - start.time
    
    time.taken
```

**Results:**

```
time.taken
Time difference of 0.01959896 secs

$xmin
[1] 0.9949586 0.9949586

$fmin
[1] 1.989918

$niter
[1] 3
```

**References:**

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/vignettes/GA.html
- https://rdrr.io/rforge/pracma/man/steep_descent.html

Comment: Note as well that there are numerous derived techniques. For example, there are many techniques which rarely (if ever) need to calculate the full gradient, and instead rely on sub-gradients. In particular for ML, these methods tend to be stochastic and to do better (in terms of error rates) when compared with non-stochastic techniques - in other words, they "optimize worse but generalize better".

Answer (score 2):

Well, it sounds like you already know the answer: of course mutating a feature vector is faster than computing the derivative of the objective function.  But that doesn't mean that genetic programming is overall more effective or more efficient than gradient descent.  It is comparing the running time of one step, but ignores the number of steps you take.  As a result, this fact is not very informative for helping us choose an optimization procedure.

(I don't know what second derivatives have to do with the question; gradient descent uses first derivatives, not second derivatives.)

(I've never heard a claim that evolutionary programming is "computationally cheaper" than gradient descent, so I'm not sure where that is coming from.)

Comment: @ D.W. : thank you for your answer! I made that correction about the 2nd derivatives (i wanted to compare evolutionary  algorithms to gradient methods and full newton methods - full newton methods generally involve calculating or approximating the Hessian i.e. second derivatives)